# spring dependencies in my project hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jar

The whole day I am working on that problem.
I have a workspace with this structur:

- cmn-lib (common basic algorithms) # Java
- cmn-server (common server based logic) # Java
- cmn-dao (database interface) # Java
- qz-tomcat (tomcat project) # Java
- qz-client (client) # Android

cmn-server as well as cmn-dao using Spring(The tests runs without problems).
the spring configuration of cmn-server-spring.xml includes the common-dao-spring.xml(Becouse some Handler classes needs Dao support).
This is the cmn-server-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <import resource="cmn-dao-spring.xml" />
    <bean id="scoreHandler" class="de.bc.qz.handler.score.ScoreHandler"
        autowire="byName">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

now I want to include all those librarys into qz-tomcat.
The problem is that exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative location [cmn-dao-spring.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/BC/qz/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/quiz-tomcat/WEB-INF/lib/cmn-server.jar!/cmn-serv-spring.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/BC/qz/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/quiz-tomcat/WEB-INF/lib/cmn-server.jar!/cmn-dao-spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: JAR entry cmn-dao-spring.xml not found in C:\Users\BC\qz\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\quiz-tomcat\WEB-INF\lib\cmn-server.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
```

It occurs when I start my local tomcat.
cmn-server and cmn-dao are included as JAR with help of "Web Deployment Assembly".

However... My webapp brokes during `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`:

```
@WebServlet("/ScoreServlet")
public class ScoreServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    ScoreHandler mScoreHandler;
    @Autowired
    TransferAdapter mTransferAdapter;

    ScoreCreator mScoreCreator;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
                config.getServletContext());
    }
```

Is something wrong in my cmn-server.jar?
I think the main problem is that line in the exception:

```
IOException parsing XML document from URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/BC/qz/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/quiz-tomcat/WEB-INF/lib/cmn-server.jar!/cmn-dao-spring.xml
```

There is no common-dao-spring.xml in my cmn-server.jar. I have added the project cmn-dao to cmn-server via `Java Build Path->Project->Add->cmn-dao`
That configuration seems to be fine for JUnit tests but not for the deployed Jar-File.

Knows anybody how to fix that problem.

Thanks for each help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep your Spring configuration files in the jars they belong to, and it's not a bad idea to use the standard `META-INF/spring` location. What you want to do is tell Spring to look for the configuration file on the classpath:

```
<import resource="classpath:[/META-INF/spring]/cmn-dao.xml" />
```

Also, note that you apparently have a mismatch in your naming, which may be the only problem actually breaking your runtime: You constantly switch back and forth between `cmn` and `common` and having or not having `spring` at the end. Pick one convention and use it.

Comment: so you mean I remove the dao-reference from the cmn-server-spring.xml and make the location via your example? Do you have a reference link for a tutorial? The difference of naming is only in my question...

Comment: Note that `META-INF` is not generally on the classpath.

Comment: @StefanBeike The question in your comment is unclear. Fix your question, then; don't post "this is kind-of-like my real problem" code. I'm saying that you use `classpath:` to tell Spring to look for an imported context XML file in another jar on the classpath. All the other usual rules apply.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Not sure what you mean by "not generally on the classpath"; it's usual practice to put Spring config files in `META-INF/spring` (under `src/main/resources` or whatever), and those are packaged in the jars. The `classpath:` directive tells Spring to look for that file in the different classpath options, such as in the library jars.

Comment: In a web application, [ex. tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions), only files/classes under `WEB-INF/classes` and jars in `WEB-INF/lib` will be put on the classpath. So if a jar contains a `META-INF/wtv` file, this will work, but it won't if the `META-INF` is in the web application itself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think I see what you're saying. I've always seen the `META-INF/spring` location used *relative to* jar-packaged Spring components that are put in `WEB-INF/libs` for a Web application, where only the final top-level artifact is war-packaged. The top-level config does have to go in `WEB-INF` (but not necessarily `lib`; I've used `WEB-INF/spring`). These days I'm happy to avoid XML at all if possible, and I'm liking the Spring Boot approach of embedded containers.

Comment: @chrylis I found a good step by step tutorial(http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/) which using spring as you described. I'll continue with that next weekend. then I accept your answer.